# I am trying to make an android app in which I want to make a chat function within 2 devices using WiFi router

Tags: android, wifip2p

I am trying to make an android app in which I want to make a chat function within 2 devices using **WiFi router** Need help

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create something like a LAN-chat I would advise you to use bluetooth instead of your Router ;)

Comment: Actually its my project to make something like LAN chat